# Serious issue with file-roller, it crashes constantly?

Tags: 11.04, lubuntu, file-roller

When I open file-roller from terminal, it shows these warnings:

```
(file-roller:8301): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_provider_get_style_property: assertion `g_type_is_a (gtk_widget_path_get_object_type (path), pspec->owner_type)' failed  

(file-roller:8301): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_provider_get_style_property: assertion `g_type_is_a (gtk_widget_path_get_object_type (path), pspec->owner_type)' failed  

(file-roller:8301): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_style_provider_get_style_property: assertion `g_type_is_a (gtk_widget_path_get_object_type (path), pspec->owner_type)' failed
```

when I try to open an archive from file-roller, it crashes and shows this error

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser' does not contain a key named 'last-folder-uri'  
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Also, it doesn't have any style, and it can't extract or compress files.
It doesn't work at all now!

I tried purging, switching to another user, reinstall it... and even reinstalled the whole desktop package. But still no luck :-s.

Note: my machine is on lubuntu 11.04, the problem started to happen since I removed a package (don't remember) and the package manager mistakenly removed file-roller too. Before that it works perfectly...

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this? I'm having a similar problem (on Fedora rather than Ubuntu though).

Comment: It may be related to these bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/884503 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/878993

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).